# Программно потерять пакеты UDP

Tags: c++, winsock, udp

Необходимо где-то прописать функцию Sleep на сервере, чтобы пакеты потерялись.

Клиент:

```
Network network;
    ServerUDP client;
    try
    {
        client.CreateSOCKET();
        int col = 1;
        string text = "Hello from Client";
        while (col <= 100)
        {
            string s = std::to_string(col);
            client.SendTo(text + s,client.serv);
            cout << "SEND " << s << endl;
            string answer;
        //  int bytes_recv = client.RecvFrom(answer);
        //  cout << "Recv msg: " << answer << endl << endl;
            //      cout << text + s << endl;
            col++;
        }
        client.CloseSOCKET();
    }
    catch (string errorMsgText)
    {
        cout << endl << errorMsgText;

    }
```

Сервер:

```
Network network;
    ServerUDP sUDP;
    try
    {
        sUDP.CreateSOCKET();
        if (sUDP.Bind() == 0)
        {
            //Sleep(20000);
            while (true)
            {
                string msg;
                //Sleep(100);
                int bytes_recv = sUDP.RecvFrom(msg);
                if (bytes_recv != SOCKET_ERROR)
                {
                    cout << msg << endl;
                    sUDP.SendTo(msg);
                }

                /*while (int bytes_recv = sUDP.RecvFrom(msg) && bytes_recv != SOCKET_ERROR)
                {
                    cout << msg << endl;
                    sUDP.SendTo(msg);
                }*/
                cout << "Next User" << endl;
                Sleep(100);
            }
        }
        sUDP.CloseSOCKET();
    }
```

Comment: Если вы хотите на сервере пропустить несколько пакетов, почему бы не просто скипнуть кусок данных при передаче?

Comment: Предлагаю вариант с выдергиванием ethernet-кабеля (программно).

Comment: Это задание лабораторной. "Хозяин" хочет именно так